# Error converting a string to Brazilian date format in python

Tags: python, database, datetime

I couldn't convert this date in the Brazilian standard to a date in Python. I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('5 de fevereiro de 2022', '%d-%b-%y').date()

ValueError: time data '5 de fevereiro de 2022' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'
```

My goal is to convert all dates in this format that are in a list, like this one below:

```py
['app', '5 de fevereiro de 2022', '6 de fevereiro de 2022', '7 de fevereiro de 2022', '8 de fevereiro de 2022']
```

Comment: You are asking it to find dashes.  There are no dashes in your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with another library, [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
import dateparser
values = ['app', '5 de fevereiro de 2022', '6 de fevereiro de 2022', '7 de fevereiro de 2022', '8 de fevereiro de 2022']
[dateparser.parse(x) for x in values]
```

Output:

```
    [None,
 datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 6, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 8, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

set your locale:

```
import datetime
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "portuguese_brazil") # lc name is platform-specific
datetime.datetime.strptime('5 de fevereiro de 2022', '%d de %B de %Y').date()
# datetime.date(2022, 2, 5)
```

...and most importantly, use the correct parsing directive.